# In google cloud build why is there an extra build in my build history

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

For some reason, every successful build which is triggered by changes to our code repository, has another 'associated' build. (Failed build do not 'cause'/trigger this extra build.) See attached image.

This second build does not have a source, reference, commit or trigger. Looking at the build log, it is composed of the following steps (maybe it can give a hint about what it does):

```
Step #0 - "fetcher"
Step #1 - "prep"
Step #2 - "detector"
Step #3 - "analyzer"
Step #4 - "restorer"
Step #5 - "builder"
Step #6 - "exporter"
Step #7 - "deployment-tag"
```

[image: build history]

Any idea what causes this?

**cloud build**

```
steps:
  - name: node:12.18.1
    id: 'install root packages'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['install']
  - name: node:12.18.1
    id: 'install packages for specific project'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['install']
    dir: packages/${_SERVICE_NAME}
  - name: node:12.18.1
    id: 'getting environment variables'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['run-script', 'getenv:${_STAGE}']
    env:
      - 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}'
      - 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'
    dir: packages/${_SERVICE_NAME}
  - name: node:12.18.1
    id: 'build'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['run-script', 'build']
    dir: packages/${_SERVICE_NAME}
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    id: 'deploy'
    entrypoint: 'gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', 'app.yaml']
    dir: packages/${_SERVICE_NAME}
timeout: '3600s'
```

Triggers
There are two triggers one for each package both are the same except for some custom variables.

[image: Trigger]

Comment: What are you deploying with Cloud Build? an app engine service, cloud run? A quick replication deploying a Cloud Function with Cloud Build fired by a github trigger and I did not see double cloud build steps. Is there more information about the steps you can publicly disclose?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that any one of the build steps triggers that build subsequently (eg. step `builder`)?

Common sense might suggest, that if it has no commit ID ...it probably wasn't triggered by a repository change. This can easily be tested by commenting out build steps one by one, starting from the last one step. When reaching until `builder` (or maybe some other step), it shouldn't trigger the build without commit ID anymore.

Depending what that subsequent build does, you probably could use `--cache-from`.

This obviously would be rather useless, when it's output changes every time.

But if not, this may result in ca. `1:30` less build time.

Comment: Added the build yaml and screenshot of the triggers. As you deduced, there are two triggers one for dev branch (which deploys to staging environment) and one for master to deploy to production.